# Preserve a python environment

Tags: nixos

I'm trying to excape dependency hell in some python projects by using Nix (or, rather, nixOS). The projects are quite small and not meant to be published or whatever (academic stuff, to be run once, or a few times). I had the rough idea to create a .nix-file for every project with all the package versions that are involved. However, I am failing.

I tried this in a file project.nix:

with import  {}; [ python3Packages.xlrd ]

when running "nix-env project.nix", the package is downloaded, but when I start python3 and use "import xlrd", the package is not found.
What is wrong?

Comment: You need something like `with import {}; mkShell { buildInputs = [ python3Packages.xlrd ]; }`